# What is difference between the native vlan and the default vlan

Tags: network

What is difference between Default vlan and native vlan it's always confuses me

Comment: There are many questions here about this with answers, such as tthe above linked question.

Answer (score 0):

The native vlan is the vlan to which untagged traffic belongs. When transmitted, the frame may or may not have a tag. Most switches default to untagged, but there are exceptions. (e.g. the 40G ports on the "ALE" expansion module of a nexus 9300 series switch.)

The default vlan is the vlan to which a port belongs absent explicit configuration. In most cases, this is "1", but not always.